# Exception when saving nested NSManagedObjectContext - "Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object."

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm seeing some of my users suffering this crash, though it's not reproducible, so I don't understand what it could mean. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x19968f1e0
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000184154f5c __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000198d47f80 objc_exception_throw + 52
2   Foundation                           0x00000001850e92c8 -[NSSubqueryExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 768
3   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee964 -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 188
4   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee7d0 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 228
5   Foundation                           0x00000001850e91a4 -[NSSubqueryExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 476
6   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee964 -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 188
7   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee7d0 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 228
8   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee610 -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 388
9   Foundation                           0x0000000184fee2b4 -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 276
10  Foundation                           0x0000000184fee55c -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 208
11  Foundation                           0x0000000184fee2b4 -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 276
12  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2d30c -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _objectInResults:] + 104
13  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2c868 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _preprocessUpdatedObjects:insertsInfo:deletesInfo:updatesInfo:sectionsWithDeletes:newSectionNames:treatAsRefreshes:] + 552
14  CoreData                             0x0000000183f25498 __77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1552
15  CoreData                             0x0000000183e9bc20 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192
16  CoreData                             0x0000000183e9bae8 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 216
17  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2bfe0 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 112
18  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001840fa6ac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001840f9ecc _CFXRegistrationPost + 392
20  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001840f9c4c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 56
21  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018415f434 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1528
22  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018403a834 _CFXNotificationPost + 364
23  Foundation                           0x0000000184fa62fc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
24  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2bf44 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 76
25  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2bed0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 324
26  CoreData                             0x0000000183e2a5c0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2320
27  CoreData                             0x0000000183ea4790 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 1420
28  CoreData                             0x0000000183ea50b8 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 344
29  CoreData                             0x0000000183e972ec _perform + 320
30  CoreData                             0x0000000183ea4e98 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 172
31  CoreData                             0x0000000183e29514 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1160
32  CJournal                             0x000000010019eee4 __41-[AddEditLogsWithStoryboard savePressed:]_block_invoke (AddEditLogsWithStoryboard.m:461)
33  CoreData                             0x0000000183e9bc20 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192
34  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000199541770 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
35  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000019954c9c4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 96
36  CoreData                             0x0000000183e9bb08 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 248
37  CJournal                             0x000000010019ee3c -[AddEditLogsWithStoryboard savePressed:] (AddEditLogsWithStoryboard.m:456)
38  UIKit                                0x00000001896e23e4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
39  UIKit                                0x00000001898613f8 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 164
40  UIKit                                0x00000001896e23e4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
41  UIKit                                0x00000001896e2360 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 76
42  UIKit                                0x00000001896cac88 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 412
43  UIKit                                0x00000001896cadd4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 744
44  UIKit                                0x00000001896e1c78 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 568
45  UIKit                                0x00000001896e18a8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 800
46  UIKit                                0x00000001896daadc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 780
47  UIKit                                0x00000001896aba2c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 244
48  UIKit                                0x00000001896a9f18 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5344
49  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018410c5a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
50  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018410c038 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 536
51  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000184109d38 __CFRunLoopRun + 720
52  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000184038dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
53  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018f18c088 GSEventRunModal + 176
54  UIKit                                0x0000000189712f60 UIApplicationMain + 200
55  CJournal                             0x00000001000a73c4 main (main.m:17)
56  libdyld.dylib                        0x00000001995728b8 start + 0
```

The code for when the "save" button is pressed is as follows:

```
[self.privateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.existingLog.logSectionPeriod = nil;

    if ([self.privateContext save:&error]){

        [self.privateContext.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{

            NSError *parentError = nil;
            if ([self.privateContext.parentContext save: &parentError]){

                if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedCommonAddEditViewController:)])
                    [_delegate finishedCommonAddEditViewController:self];
                else {
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            } else {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

I can't really find any details about the exception message "Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.". Anyone have any idea what this could be referring to? 
Incidentally, the NSFetchedResultsController the stack is referring to is tied to a UITableView (not collection view). It doesn't set any predicates on it, so it's not like the predicate could be causing some issue.

Would love some opinions on what this could mean by analyzing the stack trace

==== Some more details ====

A Person has one-to-many relationship with Notes. A Note has one-to-one with Person. There are different NSFetchedResultsControllers that are listening to changes that can be affected, but it's not clear from the stack trace which one has the problem:

1. one with Notes entity with a 'person == self.notesPerson" predicate
   (to show notes for this person only)
2. one with Notes entity without
   a predicate, to show all the notes in one list.
3. one with Person entity without a predicate, but with 'notes' as part of the
   "relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching" array

The AddEditLogsWithStoryboard.m lines from the stack are the first and 7th line in the code snippet (performBlockAndWait) so they don't particularly help. What would have been useful is to know which collection property it is complaining about, or which of the NSFetchedResultsControllers

Comment: Hi. Can you show the code by line numbers `(AddEditLogsWithStoryboard.m:461)` and `(AddEditLogsWithStoryboard.m:456)`?

Comment: What is your data model, how is your FRC setup, and what are you changing when this happens?  The save of the child context causes changes in the parent context, which has a FRC watching its context and as soon as the change happens, the FRC looks to see if changes have happened which it may be interested in.  Something is happening to make the FRC think it's evaluating a collection when the object is not a collection.

Comment: Most likely, at some point you assigned a non-collection object (e.g. a string) to a to-many attribute (which uses `NSSet`). There are various ways this could happen in Objective-C. That's the real problem. The crash happens when saving because that's when Core Data stumbles over the bogus data.

Comment: Added a little more detail

Comment: You have the dump.  Walk up the stack and look at the data.  You can tell which FRC is being used, and which MOC as well... along with the data.  However, this crash is happening long after you mucked up your data.  You assigned a value with the wrong data type to a relationship.  I'd bet on your option #1.